# Custom Query with Entity

Tags: java, mysql, rest, spring-mvc

Hello i have a problem with coding custom `CreateQuery` with `spring-mvc`
My models are: 
`Competence -> manyToOne -> Domaine`

How to create a custom Query to get a unique result. This is my query

```
Query q = session.createQuery(
            "SELECT x FROM Competence x WHERE x.domaine = :domaine");
q.setInteger("domaine", domaine.getId());
return (Competence) q.uniqueResult();
```

When i do this :

```
Competence isCompetenceExist = competenceService.get(domaineToAdd);
```

`isCompetenceExist is null.`

However i have `Competence` with this `Domaine` in my database.Please help me.
Sorry my english is not very good.

Comment: it looks like you could get more than 1 result from that query but you use unique. I am sure but you could try setting maxresult on the query before running it.

Comment: Why don't you use the `q.setEntity` instead of the `q.setInteger` method and pass the `domaine` entity as is? Like: `q.setEntity("domaine", domaine)`. Also inspect your log and post any useful information or error

Comment: maybe this question is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37975294/hibernate-returns-null-hql-in-query-with-manytoone

Comment: Also update your question and post your entities `Competence` and `Domaine`

Comment: I tried     q.setEntity and my code works fine. thanks you.